# Read multiple rows from a csv file using StringFromFile function in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Trying to read a new row from the data file using StringFromFile function. 
Below is my code and data file.

```
int numOfTransactions = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("POS_TRANSACTION_NUM"));
    for(int i=0; i<numOfTransactions;i++){
        addOneMessage(${_StringFromFile(data//external_50k.txt)});
        log.info("${_StringFromFile(data//external_50k.txt,,,)}");
    }
```

external_50k.txt:

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
..
50000
```

And `numOfTransactions = 3`.

So for loop will loop 3 times and I want to read and pass 10000, 10001 and 10002 in addOneMessage function and next time read 10004, 10005 and 10006...till the file with 50000 rows is exhausted.

However, currently StringFromFile does not read new row. 10000 is passed to addOneMessage 3 times

So, it is like below:

```
10000
10000
10000
10001
10001
10002
10003
```

Answer (score 2):

In general it isn't very good practice to inline function call into script, for groovy language it will prevent compilation and cause performance degradation. Perhaps there is a way to do what you need using [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) but the picture is not clear so I'll suggest a modification to your approach instead:

Given you already using some code I would suggest modifying it as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

int position; 

if (vars.getObject("position") != null) {
   position = vars.getObject("position");
}
else {
   position = 0;
}

int numOfTransactions = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("POS_TRANSACTION_NUM"));

for (int i = 0; i < numOfTransactions; i++) {
   log.info(FileUtils.readLines(new File("data/external_50k.txt")).get(position));
   position++;
}

vars.putObject("position", position);
```

References:

- [FileUtils.readLines()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File))
- [JMeterVariables.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String))
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use CSV Data Set Config instead of using scripting?

Scenario you described can be easily implemented with 3 CSV Data Set Config elements:

[image]

This test scenario does exactly the same as you described. Every CSV Data Set Config reads next entry from defined file (tab is treated as delimiter between records) and writes the value to variable (link1 in my case). Next two entries read next two and puts them into link2 and link3. Then I can easily access all three values by ${link1}, ${link2} and ${link3} in my HTTP Request body, for example. And you don't need to use While controller for that, just loop you thread as many times as you want. Every next thread iteration will repeat these steps: read 3 values from your file.